# SpriteKit red X

Tags: ios

I need a help or an advice with SprikeKit. My app/game passed Apple review, but later I got some complaints regarding graphics (big red X). I am using spriteNodeWithImageNamed for loading pictures. Is it any way to find out if the picture was loaded? I'm sure that the picture does exist. Probably, the problem is related to a memory or something else. If I put the wrong picture name in Xcode I see error output and red x but how can I catch the error - @try/@catch does not help in this case. Any inputs, hints are very appreciated.

xcode 5, iPad air

Comment: While I'm sure you're correct the image exists, could they possibly not be included in the project-file for some resolutions? Perhaps some of the assets is missing/having upper/lower-case at the beginning, are misspelled? etc... Depending on the size of the project you could simply write a test running through the atlases for the non-retina and check that each one has a matching +@2x name...

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to load any very large textures?  The max texture size for different models of iDevices vary - perhaps that's what you're running into.  If you try to load a texture that's too large for a particular device, it might fall back to that X graphic.

As far as detecting whether the texture didn't load, I don't know a way to do that, but you might be able to ensure that it loads by using SKTexture's preloadWithCompletionHandler: method to make sure it's loaded.

Also, Apple recommends not loading textures on the fly, especially if you're loading many of them in a short time span, and carefully managing texture memory by discarding SKTextures that you no longer need.  Do some preloading, and check that you're not keeping textures around that you don't need, and see if the X icons go away.